# Avoiding cast from superclass to subclass when doing inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I ran into this while working a tree problem:

```
class BTNode<T> {
    private final T value;
    private BTNode<T> parent;
    private BTNode<T> left;
    private BTNode<T> right;

    public BTNode(T aValue) { 
       value = aValue; 
       left = right = parent = null;
    }
  the obvious protected getters & setters
}
```

I later needed a subclass that only accepts Ts that are Comparable,
defines compareTo, and adds new methods that use that property.
There is nothing new the getters and setters need to do, other than
to keep Java happy.

```
class CBTNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BTNode<T> 
                        implements Comparable<CBTNode<T>> {
    CBTNode(T aValue) { super(aValue); }
    T isBST() .... calls getLeft().isBST()  // for example
}
```

Inheritance is generally straightforward, but the fact that fields of the parent class are
all typed BTNode seems to make this a lot harder than I was hoping it would
be due to class casting errors at run time.  I can create objects that are CBTNodes 
but their fields are still BTNodes and cause problems in places like isBST(). getLeft() returns a BTNode but isBST is only defined for CBTNodes.  Java didn't like it when I tried casting to CBTNode.

What is the preferred way to extend / delegate / other CBTNode?
Its not a big class--I could sever the link between the two nodes and just define CBTNode as a copy of BTNode, but with CBTNode fields, but that seems pretty ugly. 
I thought of delegating the new functionality, but would still have the problem of casting from BTNode into CBTNode, which Java objects to.  I am hoping I am overlooking an obvious, elegant approach that is just waiting to bite me on the nose.

Comment: Hmmm... I would have thought covariant return types would work if you overrode the parent getters... but I just tried it and it does not.  I was able to bury the casts in getter overrides in `CBTNode` with no compiler warnings.

Comment: I don't have an answer.  One thing I can see is that you can have a `BTNode<T>` variable or parameter `x` that is actually (at run-time) a `CBTNode`.  Say someone does `x.setParent(p)`; the compiler only knows `x` is a `BTNode`, so it can't know to check that `p` is a `CBTNode`, so _someone_ has to do a check at run-time, and I think the overriding `setParent` is the logical place for this.  (Java won't do this kind of run-time check automatically.)  If the generic is making this difficult, I'm not (yet) an expert at generic intricacies.

Comment: "Java didn't like it when I tried casting to CBTNode."  The problem is that you extended BTNode with a generic that the static compiler doesn't know how to cast to.  Define CBTNode as a simple subclass of `BTNode<T>` and the compiler should be happy.  Or arrange to do an unsafe cast.

Comment: @Thomas (and Jim):  There are a variety of "solutions" that compile, but don't run.  I tried overriding
    protected CBTNode<T> getLeft() {
        return (CBTNode<T>)super.getLeft();
    }
That compiles and runs but leads not to an unsafe cast but to a ClassCastException.  super returns a BTNode and Java doesn't want to do the cast.  I suppose because it can't match the Ts

I made left protected instead of private in BTNode and then did
    protected CBTNode<T> getLeft() {
        return (CBTNode<T>)left;
    }
Same problem.

Comment: I used generics because I wanted the value field of the node to be generic.  I also wanted to use them for the <T extends Comparable> restriction.  I could give up on the <T> so that the relation between CBTNode and its parent is clear to the compiler, but then I'm left with a node of type Object, and users have to do all the checking and casting manually.  Yuck!

So the issue is that the compiler can't tell that CBTNode<T> is a subclass of BTNode<T> because the two type variables are really different.

Maybe I should just chuck inheritance and implement CBTNode as its own class from scratch?

Comment: Sorry what?  I didn't see your comment as it wasn't on my answer. If the tree's not homogenous, you obviously can't restrict some or all of the inter-node relationships to CBTNode. If you want to ask "is a BST" on nodes, shouldn't the tree should be homogenous? Homogenous or not, inheriting the type variable T won't be the problem so don't worry about that. Perhaps we should clarify what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

As Jim said, you can override the getters - getLeft(), getRight(), getParent() -- to narrow the type.

This area is not particularly easy & the above is the only solution that really works tidily.. I've had quite a lot of code which has touched on this & very similar situations.

```
public class CBTNode<T extends Comparable<T>> 
        extends BTNode<T>
        implements Comparable<CBTNode<T>> 
        {

    @Override
    protected CBTNode<T> getParent() {return (CBTNode<T>) parent;}

    @Override
    protected CBTNode<T> getLeft() {return (CBTNode<T>) left;}

    @Override
    protected CBTNode<T> getRight() {return (CBTNode<T>) right;}
```

The other possible alternative -- genericizing the class against itself -- doesn't really work.

If you try using generic to handle this -- putting the node-type itself as a generic parameter, for example `class BTNode<T, NodeT extends BTNode>` -- you'll find that it adds a lot of complexity to the code yet doesn't actually help. (Inference doesn't work unless all type-parameters are fully specified, casting becomes painful, and it just doesn't really seem to work.)

Once of the issues is that casts between differently-bounded generics aren't legal -- generic rules are stricter, as the compiler can't verify they are legal, or test them at runtime due to erasure. The ugly workaround here, is to use two casts -- casting to a raw type first, then to the desired parameterized type.

Comment: And please put comments on my actual answer.. otherwise I don't see them.

Comment: _"super returns a BTNode"_ -- the problem is not what it's declared as, the problem is what you've actually created/instantiated. I assume you've _created the Parent or Root of the tree_ as a BTNode -- which is incompatible with the CBTNode which your tree-spanning functions require. You need to fulfill your own rules for tree structure correctly, you can't (for example) define Parent as being a CBTNode and then try & use a non-compatible instance of the base class.

Comment: I can create a tree purely of CBTNodes but the fields inherited from BTNode on each are still type BTNode.  When I try the cast as you suggested, I still get the ClassCastException.  I am currently grasping at straws like using a delegate for the node-like functionality or trying to figure a capture helper for this situation (they are mainly just for wildcards?).  This is amazingly difficult for something that seems conceptually simple.

Comment: If the cast fails, there's a BTNode (not CBTNode) somewhere. Find & debug the error. I use code patterns -- trees, doubly-linked lists -- similar to the one I have given you successfully numerous times. Put some `if (! (parent instanceof CBTNode)) Debug.error()` statements around the **setters** and **constructors**, to capture where it's being set from. Fix that & everything will work. _(Debug being a static class I create & use for error-trapping such as this.)_